# How can I add an equation number to a special matrix

Tags: tables, equations, formatting, matrices

I want to assign an equation number to the following matrix equation; I want a number in brackets on the right side, after the equation.

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{kbordermatrix}
    \begin{document}
    \[ C = \raisebox{-2\baselineskip}{%
       \begin{tabular}[b]{c@{\hspace*{0.5em}}c}
       & To node
       \\
         \begin{sideways}
           From node
         \end{sideways}
       & \raisebox{0.5\height}%
           {\(\kbordermatrix
                { &  1  &   2 &  3  &  4  &  5  \\
                1 &  1  & x_1 & x_5 &  0  &  0 \\
                2 & x_1 &  1  & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\
                3 & x_5 & x_2 &  1  & x_6 &  0  \\
                4 &  0  & x_3 & x_6 &  1  & x_7 \\
                5 &  0  & x_4 &  0  & x_7 & 1
                }
            \)%
           }
       \end{tabular}}
    \]
    \end{document}
```

As shown in the picture. I tried several attempts but errors appear.
[image]

Comment: Change `\[...\]` to `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{kbordermatrix}
    \begin{document}
   % \[
    \begin{equation} % here
 C = \raisebox{-2\baselineskip}{%
       \begin{tabular}[b]{c@{\hspace*{0.5em}}c}
       & To node
       \\
         \begin{sideways}
           From node
         \end{sideways}
       & \raisebox{0.5\height}%
           {\(\kbordermatrix
                { &  1  &   2 &  3  &  4  &  5  \\
                1 &  1  & x_1 & x_5 &  0  &  0 \\
                2 & x_1 &  1  & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\
                3 & x_5 & x_2 &  1  & x_6 &  0  \\
                4 &  0  & x_3 & x_6 &  1  & x_7 \\
                5 &  0  & x_4 &  0  & x_7 & 1
                }
            \)%
           }
       \end{tabular}}
   % \]
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```